# display different text on different links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this when i click on photos the target div gallery gets displayed.I want to display the target div with some effects like ease-in or ease-out or slide effects etc. so that it looks more attractive.Initially the target div gallery is not displayed as in css there is display:none for gallery.I also tried the transition property for this but its not working.So plz help me with this.

```
<div>   
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#main">Home</a></li>
        <li id="gallary"><a href="#gallery">Photos</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>

 <div id="gallery">
     <h3 style="font-family:'Comic Sans MS';color:white;font-size:25px;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;">GALLARY</h3>
     <div id="gallary_images"><a href="slide1.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="slide1.jpg"/></a></div>
     <div id="gallary_images"><a href="slide3.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="slide3.jpg"/></a></div>
     <div id="gallary_images"><a href="slide4.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="slide4.jpg"/></a></div>
     <div id="gallary_images"><a href="slide5.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="slide5.jpg"/></a></div>
     <div id="gallary_images"><a href="slide1.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="slide1.jpg"/></a></div>
     <div id="gallary_images"><a href="slide5.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="slide5.jpg"/></a></div>
</div>
```

the **CSS** for this is

```
#gallery:target
{
    display:block;
    }
#gallery
{
    border:solid black thin;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    }
```

Comment: I can't seem to understand your question but I noticed something else:
You use the id "gallery" twice: once in ``<li id="gallary">``, the second time in ``<div id="gallary">``. You **must not** use ids twice in one html document. It will work most of the times, but you can never know what will happen as a result. Same goes for all the ``<div id="gallary_images">`` tags.
And lastly: the word your looking for is "**gallery**".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like this jQuery function is suitable for your needs:

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

There is an example on the above page, which I've modified for you to try out:

```
$( "#gallary" ).click(function() {
  $( "#gallery" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete
  });
});
```

I've assumed you want to click on `<li id="gallary"><a href="#gallery">Photos</a></li>` to make the contents of  appear.

If I may add a couple of further comments - try renaming your element ids to be more descriptive, and to be aware you've used both 'gallary' and 'gallery' spellings which makes it hard to read. Also, a single id should be unique, whilst the same class can be used multiple times.

Finally - don't use comic sans! :D

Edit: I've added your extra requirement to close on backspace:

```
$('html').keyup(function(e){if(e.keyCode == 8)
  $( "#gallery" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete
  });})
```

As I mentioned in comment 8 = backspace, 36 = escape key.

Comment: its working.Thank u for that.But there is a problem.When i press backspace on keyboard the gallery content should disappear but it is not so.

Comment: Hi, this should be possible with jquery:

$('html').keyup(function(e){if(e.keyCode == 8)
  $( "#gallery" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete
  });})  

In the above I've used keycode 8 which is backspace. You can also use 36 which is the escape key.

Comment: but if there are more than one div like if i have 3 or more div to be displayed so how can i solve this backspace problem where i have to show the just previous content.